# Cordova build error "Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.2"

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework

when I try to compile with ionic my application tells me the following error:

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/jmarroni/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Try installing the previous version of java 1.8 but do not recognize the change.

Comment: Then you haven't installed Java 8 properly. Make sure to totally uninstall and DELETE any remaining Java folders, then restart the computer. Afterwards, install Java 8 using the provided installer from the Java website.

Comment: is it necessary to have java 8 to use cordova. I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 4):

I’ve faced the same problem. In my case, two different JDK are installed

/usr/lib/jvm$ default-java java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 java-11-openjdk-amd64 java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 java-8-openjdk-amd64 openjdk-11

1. sudo update-alternatives --config java
2. sudo update-alternatives --config javac

Comment: Thanks. The javac part is important

Answer (score 3):

I will put in one place all the information:

- Version 8 of Java JDK. I was unable to find quickly the openjdk-8 version, so I decided to install Oracle version
- Setting `JAVA_HOME` is **not** needed

1. Proceed to

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

2. Download:

```
jdk-8u251-linux-x64.tar.gz or newest
```

3. Login with oracle account
4. Uncompress it in `/opt`

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/jdk-8u251-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt
cd /opt
sudo tar xfz jdk-8u251-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo ln -s jdk1.8.0_251 java
```

5. Make `java` binary point to desired SDK

5.1. Install alternative

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/java/bin/java 2
```

5.2. Activate it

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

5.3. Select the entry added in step 4.1.

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1411      auto mode
  1            /opt/java/bin/java                            2         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1411      manual mode
```

In this case type `1` and press `Enter`

5.4. Test

Type:

```
java -version
```

Expected output similar to:

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

6. Make `javac` binary point to desired SDK

6.1. Install alternative

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/java/bin/javac 2
```

6.2. Activate it

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

6.3. Select the entry added in step 6.1.

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1411      auto mode
* 1            /opt/java/bin/javac                            2         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1411      manual mode
```

In this case type `1` and press `Enter`

6.4. Test

Type:

```
javac -version
```

Expected output similar to:

```
javac 1.8.0_251
```

if the output is similar to the output of "java -version", make sure you've written the correct command in section 6.1 with the missing "c" of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me.
PAY ATTENTION!
6.1 : the original post had a typo (a missing "c").
the command should be: "sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/java/bin/javac 2"